# Practically, how feasible it is to define an area with beacons?

Tags: altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

I want to define an area with a certain number of beacons. Theoretically it should be possible, Is it possible practically? Because the distance value that i get fluctuates erratically.

Comment: What goal are you trying to accomplish with the beacons?

Comment: @davidgyoung To see if a bluetooth device such as an android phone is within an area that I define with beacons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you'd want to figure out an exact position of a person based on trilateration from multiple beacons in the area? Like you said, it is quite hard with the sporadic signal transmission. There's some SDKs that exist for this, such as the Proximi.io free SDK and platform (http://proximi.io)